# Dynamic soql query passing null ID value

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

Using a dynamic soql query in my managed package , In my where condition am passing id value,

```
string whereCond = NameSpace('fldName') +' = \'' +keyType+ '\'' +' and ' + NameSpace('fldName') +' = \'' +obj.Id+ '\'' +' ORDER BY ' + NameSpace('fldName') +' asc '
```

if my obj.ID is null , its passing as **'Null'** (with single quotation)  am getting a error that **INVALID field ID : NULL** ,

`NameSpace('fldName') +' = :'+obj.Id` when I tried this code error in Dynamic soql query .
In my test class i want to pass a null ID

Comment: Do you not want `null` to go through the soql? or do you want to pass `null` in the test class?

Comment: You are getting 'NULL' with quotes because you are using ' = \'' +obj.Id+ '\'' in your SOQL Query. You need to validate your  obj.Id  should not be null. then your query will run.

Comment: thanks guys :) yeah i want to pass null ID in test class, yeah validated before passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a method which implements a more generic approach.

```
public static String buildFilter(String field, String value)
{
    if (value != null)
        value = '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(value) + '\''
    return field + '=' + value; 
}
```

Then you would use this method instead.

```
query += 'WHERE ' + builder(namespace('fieldName'), value);
```

Answer (score 3):

As the above said just add this to the beginning of your method

```
If(obj == null  || obj.Id == null){
     //throw and error or return empty list
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy it helped :) error occurs only in test class